# Sorting number with comma in react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Using react-bootstrap-table2, When trying to filter large numbers with commas (12,000) it doesn't work. Is it possible to filter numbers with commas?

example 
[image]

Cheers!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Sort the columns?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to sort the columns. When it's converted to a string to achieve the comma it doesn't work. I was hoping there was a simple solution built into the plugin react-bootstrap-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code it is hard to say. But perhaps each cell data in your table is a string, not a number, which could cause sorting weirdness. I had same issue before. Sort it by number, then populate your table cells with the formatted string version of the number after sort, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah that makes sense. I was hoping the react-bootstrap-table plugin would have a setting that takes care this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that:

- your field name is "estimation"
- thousands separator is ' (apostrophe)
- decimal separator is , (comma)

You can write your sort function (`sortFunc`) as follows:

```
{
    dataField: 'estimation',
    text: 'Estimation',
    sort: true,
    sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField, rowA, rowB) => {
    const numA = parseFloat(a.replace('\'', '').replace(',', '.'));
    const numB = parseFloat(b.replace('\'', '').replace(',', '.'));
    if (order === "asc") {
        return numB - numA;
    }
    return numA - numB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this problem, here is my Bootstrap Table sort function。**

```
 sortFunc: (a, b, order) => {
    const numA = parseFloat(a.replace(/\,/g,''), 10)
    const numB = parseFloat(b.replace(/\,/g,''), 10)
    if (order === "asc") {
        return numB - numA;
    }
    return numA - numB;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import ToolkitProvider, { Search } from "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit";
import paginationFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator";
```

First please check number or non-number.

1. If your array inside number return number else is non-number  :

   ```
   yourDataArray.map(function (item, x) {
     item._Number_of_stocks = parseInt(item.Number_of_stocks);
   });
   ```
2. Sort function in here:

   ```
   sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField, rowA, rowB) => {
     if (order === "asc") {
       return (
         isNaN(rowB._Number_of_stocks) - !isNaN(rowB._Number_of_stocks)
       );
     }
     return !isNaN(rowB._Number_of_stocks) - isNaN(rowB._Number_of_stocks);
   },
   ```

See: https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/blob/master/docs/columns.md